# Home ownership vs renting

Tags: home-house

From the perspective of Judiasm is there any significance to owning a home instead of renting? Would there be any Halachic or Hashkafik reasons that would make one of the above preferable?

Comment: Do you have any possible reason to think that there might be one. If not, then one could generate an infinite number of questions, relating to every point in his life; down to the colour of his tie.

Comment: The Torah and a good portion of the book of Joshua speaks about land ownership and land divisions. Interestingly enough, it does not explicitly mention anywhere the notion of building houses on that land, though, I would imagine that this idea is implied. I don't think the idea of land ownership was to keep people living in tents as they did while wandering through the desert. To rent a home, obviously, someone must own it. But, I don't think there is any "significance" other than something like the responsibility of placing a mezuzah which is usually upon the owner rather than the renter.

Comment: @DanD _m'zuza_ is incumbent on the resident afaik. And Deut. says one who has just built a house is exempt from the draft.

Answer (score 1):

[The Pele yoets writes regarding this under building](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=31&t=2&Search=Rent)

The link above has audio and text in English

It seems he holds it is better to rent, especially if it is not in Israel , unless the person is very rich, then he should invest in real estate

---

Also see [dwelling](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=71&t=&Search=) and [Isreal](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=13&t=&Search=)